# How do I change custom url links in Drupal 7?

Tags: url, drupal-7, seo, alias, custom-url

I am using a drupal 7 website. My default page url is website.com/category/4

I want to change this url like website.com/category/title

Please suggest to me the change syntax.

Comment: Can’t you use the same way you used to change it to `/category/4`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. It allows you to set URL patterns per entity type (i.e. content types, taxonomies, users, etc.) with tokens (i.e. title, entity id, etc.).